# getAccountsByType does not return anything in marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

Now this is odd...

Using

```
AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[] {"com.google"}, null, null, null, null);
```

does give me a list of accounts. But using

```
AccountManager.get(context).getAccountsByType("com.google")
```

returns 0 accounts. The problem only happens in marshmallow.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

still exists in the manifest.

Any ideas...?

UPDATE:
Turns out, must ask permission for GET_ACCOUNTS, even though docs say otherwise... (see comments)

Comment: Have you requested permission for getting accounts? This permission is on the list that user has to allow

Comment: @Billda this one? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

Comment: Yes, ive seen it in g+ community yesterday, heres a link https://plus.google.com/+BrendonSled/posts/jdrHS3GC7c6

Comment: Does `getAccounts()` return anything?

Comment: @Billda bingo, sir! nice find. thank you! official docs still list it as a safe permission... Would you like to post an official answer for it?

Comment: You only need the GET_ACCOUNTS permission on Marshmallow if you are accessing accounts not created by your App. If you are using AccountManager to store you user's credentials and don't need to access the Google (or other non-app) accounts you can qualify the GET_ACCOUNTS permission on your manifest with android:maxSdkVersion="22". If you do need GET_ACCOUNTS on Marshmallow then you need to check for that permission at runtime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to this g+ post https://plus.google.com/+BrendonSled/posts/jdrHS3GC7c6 permission GET_ACCOUNTS is now listed as dangerous and user has to allow it

Comment: According to documentation of "final SDK", protection level = normal https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_ACCOUNTS Anyway, your link pointed to the solution ^^

Comment: @shkschneider I might be missing something but why does it return null instead of throwing a SecurityException like with other permissions (location for example). There are no warnings so the only way I found out about this was when I saw my app crashing...

Comment: @fersarr you're not missing something. it's something badly implemented as of now. yes, it returns null instead of raising a SecurityException :/

Answer (score 3):

For anyone getting here, the real answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49894280)

in short, you need to use `AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent()` ([ref](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#newChooseAccountIntent%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.accounts.Account%3E,%20java.lang.String[],%20boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20android.os.Bundle%29))