# Get all Registered Email Accounts in Android

Tags: android, email

I basically want to give option to user to select the email ID user wants. I don't want the contacts permission from user. Though account permission is fine with user. I tried [answer at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address) but it is not working for me. Is there any other way of getting it?

What I have tried:

Add this permission to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

And then request the google accounts like this:

```
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType("com.google");
for (Account account : accounts) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Found: " + account.name);
}
```

Comment: Did you visited this link: http://androidexample.com/Get_Registered_Email_Accounts_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=110 ?

Comment: Yes. That  is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to having the uses-permission line in the manifest, you also have to grant that permission when the app is installed. If you have a new device, it's possible that it's Off. Check the app's permissions in your Settings. That fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more below permission in manifes. it's working for me. I answered on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050548/android-accountmanager-getaccounts-returns-an-empty-array/49849967#49849967).

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add permission in the manifest below android 6.0 else request run time permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Then get accounts using AccountManager.

```
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccounts();
```

Answer (score -1):

Request the google accounts like this:

```
Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccounts();
for (Account account : accounts) {
    if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
        String emailAccount = account.name;
    }
}
```