# Determining if a Google Account is available

Tags: android

How can I determine on Android 8 and above devices if a Google Account is available.
Since Android 8 (Target SDK 26) the following code returns an empty result

```
Account[] accArray = accMan.getAccountsByType("com.google");
```

Several other developers that work with getAccountsByType have the same problem
[Android: AccountManager.getAccounts() returns an empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050548/android-accountmanager-getaccounts-returns-an-empty-array)

I don't want to access data from the account. I just want to determine if a specific type (here com.google) is present.

Comment: Do you specify the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission in your manifest and request it on runtime?

Comment: Yes i specified the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission in the manifest. I also check the permission with the following code.

`ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)`

But this isn't enough anymore, Android changed in Android 8. But it would be enough for me to detect the presence of a Google Account. I don't need to access it.