# Android get logged in email name programmatically. Android AccountManager not working

Tags: android, accountmanager

I have to fetch logged in email. I am trying to fetch using AccountManager. Here is my code

```
private void getEmails() {
        Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS;

        // Getting all registered Google Accounts;
         Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType("com.google");

        // Getting all registered Accounts;
//        Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();

        for (Account account : accounts) {
            if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s - %s", account.name, account.type));
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried both option
AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType("com.google");
AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();

Both are returning empty body.

Please help me.

Comment: Do you have permission `android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS`

Comment: Yes I have added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" /> in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: If you need JAVA version of the answer do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add permission

> android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS

Kotlin implementation

```
val manager = getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE) as AccountManager
    manager.accounts.forEach {
        if(it.type.equals("com.google",true))
         {
           Log.e(TAG,"${it.name}")
         }
     }
```

After some more research I came to know that you should have below permission as well.

> Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS

Request permission at runtime

```
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 1);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS}, 1);
```

Java implementation

```
 AccountManager manager = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
    
            for (Account account : manager.getAccounts()) {
                if (account.type.equalsIgnoreCase("com.google")) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Mail: "+account.name);
                }
            }
```

User **Thomas Thomas** states the above permission is necessary as well [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050548/android-accountmanager-getaccounts-returns-an-empty-array)

Comment: Its now working. List coming empty.

Comment: Do you have any mail associated with  Gmail in that device? I have tested at my end its working properly.

Comment: Gmail is configured in my device. But with this code its not showing

Comment: check out updated answer @AmitYadav. Hope it works for you now.

Comment: It was returning null array on Android 12 at my end too. Then after adding `READ_CONTACTS` permission its working fine