# Android sdk23 find places to update and request permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

May be I am missing something, but is there a way to quickly know all the places I have to update with the new permission checks needed for Android apps using sdk23?

As a developer this change is very frustrating considering the multiple places that need to be updated. I would like to make sure I don't forget/miss any of them.

I am talking about finding where it will be needed to use these two functions before using the permissions qualified as 'Dangerous'

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()
```

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Dangerous permissions
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous

**EDIT**

In some cases the code throws SecurityException like when trying to use **location** without the granted permission. But in other cases it just returns null like here

```
AccountManager.get(context).getAccountsByType("com.google")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Android Studio, open the Analyze menu and run Inspect Code...  In the results, open Android and then Constant and Resource Type Mismatches.  Look for entries that start with "Call requires permission..."

Comment: There are extra cases that were not caught by this and I only found out when my app was crashing: AccountManager.get(context).getAccountsByType("com.google") returned null instead of throwing SecurityException. Read more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32162164/getaccountsbytype-does-not-return-anything-in-marshmallow

Comment: Good catch. If anyone sees this and knows any other cases that android lint doesn't catch, post a comment.

Comment: this method doesn't catch all the permission,like in my case of all the permissions it only detected location.

Comment: What if I'm not using Android Studio? How do I find all the code paths that need runtime permission checking?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry.